# Matlab adapting comments to a certain length per line

Tags: matlab, formatting, indentation, comments

I like MATLAB automatically linebreaking comments on a certain limit per line. Now let's assume I have added the following comment:

```
% a) this is a test comment. this is a test comment. this is a test comment
%    this is a test comment. this is a test comment. this is a test
%    comment! this is a test comment!
```

with a manual indentation at the beginning (to fit the `a)`). Now when I need to change a bit of the comment, e.g. inserting some words into the first line, the first line gets too long. How can I automatically get it newly formated to the correct max. line length but still with the manual indentation?
Is there any automatical way to do this?

Comment: Matlab breaks the line only if you type a character at the end of the line. So after adding your changes, type a single character at the end of the line to auto-break it.

Comment: That's a good hint, but still, you have to indent yourself and than remove the following linebreak so that the following commentline is displayed behind your breaked comment line since it is too short. I know it sounds weird, but simply try it and you'll see the problem.

Comment: I am aware of that, that's why I hate this feature and disabled it :-)

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best you can do requires three steps on your part.

When you initially add some text, it looks like this:

```
% a) this is a test comment. this is a test comment. ADDED TEXT this is a test comment
%    this is a test comment. this is a test comment. this is a test
%    comment! this is a test comment!
```

First, select the text (or the whole file via CTRL+a) and then issue the "wrap comments" command using CTRL+J .  Now your text looks like this:

```
% a) this is a test comment. this is a test comment. ADDED TEXT this is a
% test comment
%    this is a test comment. this is a test comment. this is a test
%    comment! this is a test comment!
```

Second, you have to manually indent that first line, so the text looks like this:

```
% a) this is a test comment. this is a test comment. ADDED TEXT this is a
%    test comment
%    this is a test comment. this is a test comment. this is a test
%    comment! this is a test comment!
```

Third, select text and use CTRL+J again.  Your text will look like:

```
% a) this is a test comment. this is a test comment. ADDED TEXT this is a
%    test comment this is a test comment. this is a test comment. this is a
%    test comment! this is a test comment!
```

It's not perfect, but it is as good as I am aware of within the Matlab editor.

Comment: WOW! Didn't know about Ctrl+J, it's easy and effective! No more reformatting... Thanks a lot!!!